# Eclipse - A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

i'm trying to add a server to do Java EE aplications, and the moment i click in "no servers are available. Click this link to create a new server" the Eclipse close, and in the folder appears a text document, with the following:

```
    #
    # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f648c3c8435, pid=3088, tid=140070770353920
    #
    # JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_55-b14) (build 1.7.0_55-b14)
    # Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
    # Problematic frame:
    # C  [libgtk-3.so.0+0x272435]  gtk_tree_model_get_valist+0xf5
    #
    # Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
    #
    # If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
    # instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
    #   http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
    # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
    # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
    #

    ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

    Current thread (0x00007f64bc00a800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=3089, stack(0x00007f64c472a000,0x00007f64c482b000)]

    siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x0000000000000030

    Registers:
    RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x00007f64c4826928, RCX=0x00007f64bc000050, RDX=0x0000000000000000
    RSP=0x00007f64c4826870, RBP=0x00007f64bd3fcb30, RSI=0x00000000ffffffff, RDI=0x00007f64c48268a0
    R8 =0x00007f64b90102a0, R9 =0x00007f64bc00aee8, R10=0x00007f64c3a0bee0, R11=0x00007f64775d51bb
    R12=0x00007f64c48268a0, R13=0x00007f64c4826880, R14=0x00007f64bde99f70, R15=0x00007f648c528d20
    RIP=0x00007f648c3c8435, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
      TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

    Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007f64c4826870)
    0x00007f64c4826870:   0000000000000001 0000000000000000
    0x00007f64c4826880:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
    0x00007f64c4826890:   0000000000000000 00007f646aae51fa
    0x00007f64c48268a0:   00000000ffffffff 00007f648f36c522
    0x00007f64c48268b0:   00007f648f326bb8 00007f64bc1e3840
    0x00007f64c48268c0:   00007f64c4826990 6285ae97560ddf00
    0x00007f64c48268d0:   0000000000000000 00007f64bde99f70
    0x00007f64c48268e0:   00007f64bd3fcb30 00007f64bd3fcb30
    0x00007f64c48268f0:   00007f64bde99f70 00007f64bd4275e0
    0x00007f64c4826900:   00007f64bd3fcb30 00007f64bde99f70
    0x00007f64c4826910:   0000000000000000 00007f648c3c874c
    0x00007f64c4826920:   0000000000000008 0000003000000018
    0x00007f64c4826930:   00007f64c4826a10 00007f64c4826940
    0x00007f64c4826940:   0000000000000000 00007f64bd4275e0
    0x00007f64c4826950:   0000000000000000 00007f64bd4275e0
    0x00007f64c4826960:   00000000ffffffff 00007f64c4826af0
    0x00007f64c4826970:   00007f64bc00a800 00007f64bc6f5911
    0x00007f64c4826980:   0000000000000000 6285ae97560ddf00
    0x00007f64c4826990:   00007f64c4826af0 00007f64bc00a800
    0x00007f64c48269a0:   00007f64c4826af0 0000000000000000
    0x00007f64c48269b0:   00000000fa3f9df0 00007f64bc00a800
    0x00007f64c48269c0:   00007f64c4826a00 00007f64c3223cb2
    0x00007f64c48269d0:   00007f64c4826a10 00007f64bc00a9d8
    0x00007f64c48269e0:   0000000000000000 00007f64bd3fcb30
    0x00007f64c48269f0:   00007f64bde99f70 00007f64bc00a9d8
    0x00007f64c4826a00:   00007f64c4826af0 00007f647735455c
    0x00007f64c4826a10:   00007f64c4826a70 00000000d0f3a540
    0x00007f64c4826a20:   00007f64c4826ac8 0000000000000000
    0x00007f64c4826a30:   00000000d0f3a540 00007f64c4826b18
    0x00007f64c4826a40:   00007f64bc00a800 00007f64b9012738
    0x00007f64c4826a50:   00000000ffffffff 00000000d10e3056
    0x00007f64c4826a60:   00007f64bc00b358 00000000fffffffe 

    Instructions: (pc=0x00007f648c3c8435)
    0x00007f648c3c8415:   8e df 01 00 00 4c 89 e9 4c 89 f6 48 89 ef e8 68
    0x00007f648c3c8425:   f0 ff ff 48 8b 7c 24 10 e8 ee a9 df ff 4c 89 e7
    0x00007f648c3c8435:   48 8b 50 30 49 89 c2 b9 08 00 00 00 31 c0 45 31
    0x00007f648c3c8445:   c0 f3 48 ab 42 0f b6 0c 02 84 c9 74 4f 83 e9 64 

    Register to memory mapping:

    RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
    RBX=0x00007f64c4826928 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f64bc00a800
    RCX=0x00007f64bc000050 is an unknown value
    RDX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
    RSP=0x00007f64c4826870 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f64bc00a800
    RBP=0x00007f64bd3fcb30 is an unknown value
    RSI=0x00000000ffffffff is an unknown value
    RDI=0x00007f64c48268a0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f64bc00a800
    R8 =0x00007f64b90102a0 is at code_begin+0 in an Interpreter codelet
    method entry point (kind = zerolocals)  [0x00007f64b90102a0, 0x00007f64b90105e0]  832 bytes
    R9 =0x00007f64bc00aee8 is an unknown value
    R10=0x00007f64c3a0bee0: <offset 0xdb3ee0> in /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so at 0x00007f64c2c58000
    R11=0x00007f64775d51bb: fn6_4+0 in /home/gabriel/Área de Trabalho/Eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/673/0/.cp/libswt-gtk-4427.so at 0x00007f6477579000
    R12=0x00007f64c48268a0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f64bc00a800
    R13=0x00007f64c4826880 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f64bc00a800
    R14=0x00007f64bde99f70 is an unknown value
    R15=0x00007f648c528d20: <offset 0x3d2d20> in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0 at 0x00007f648c156000


    Stack: [0x00007f64c472a000,0x00007f64c482b000],  sp=0x00007f64c4826870,  free space=1010k
    Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
    C  [libgtk-3.so.0+0x272435]  gtk_tree_model_get_valist+0xf5

    Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
    j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._gtk_tree_model_get(JJI[JI)V+0
    j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.gtk_tree_model_get(JJI[JI)V+15
    j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo.clearText()V+78
    j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo.setItems([Ljava/lang/String;)V+66
    j  org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.wizard.page.NewManualServerComposite.updateRuntimeCombo(Lorg/eclipse/wst/server/core/IServerType;)V+237
    j  org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.wizard.page.NewManualServerComposite.handleHostnameChange(Lorg/eclipse/wst/server/core/IServerType;)V+86
    j  org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.wizard.page.NewManualServerComposite.setHost(Ljava/lang/String;)V+23
    j  org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.wizard.page.NewManualServerComposite$2.hostnameSelected(Ljava/lang/String;)V+5
    j  org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.wizard.page.NewManualServerComposite.hostnameChanged(Ljava/lang/String;)V+18
    j  org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.wizard.page.NewManualServerComposite$HostnameChangedAction$1.run()V+14
    j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run()V+11
    j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Z)Z+37
    j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Z)Z+5
    j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch()Z+61
    j  org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Shell;)V+23
    j  org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open()I+49
    j  org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.cnf.ServersView2$1.widgetSelected(Lorg/eclipse/swt/events/SelectionEvent;)V+28
    j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V+1133
    J  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V
    j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/EventTable;Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V+7
    j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V+26
    j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(ILorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;Z)V+73
    j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendSelectionEvent(ILorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;Z)V+140
    j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Link.gtk_button_release_event(JJ)J+157
    j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.windowProc(JJJ)J+378
    j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(JJJ)J+324
    j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(JJJ)J+20
    v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
    j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._gtk_main_do_event(J)V+0
    j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.gtk_main_do_event(J)V+8
    j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.eventProc(JJ)J+157
    v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
    j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._g_main_context_iteration(JZ)Z+0
    j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.g_main_context_iteration(JZ)Z+9
    j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch()Z+36
    j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run()V+638
    j  org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Lorg/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/Realm;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+12
    j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/MApplicationElement;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/contexts/IEclipseContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+57
    j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/MApplicationElement;)V+20
    j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run()V+310
    j  org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Lorg/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/Realm;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+12
    j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;)I+18
    j  org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;)I+2
    j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(Lorg/eclipse/equinox/app/IApplicationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+111
    j  org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+135
    j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+85
    j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+82
    j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+109
    j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Ljava/lang/Object;+132
    v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
    j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
    j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
    j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
    j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+57
    j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework([Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/net/URL;)V+211
    j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun([Ljava/lang/String;)V+160
    j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run([Ljava/lang/String;)I+4
    j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+10
    v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

    ---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

    Java Threads: ( => current thread )
      0x00007f64bdf66800 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=3136, stack(0x00007f64748e8000,0x00007f64749e9000)]
      0x00007f64bd4ff000 JavaThread "Worker-6" [_thread_blocked, id=3133, stack(0x00007f64740e8000,0x00007f64741e9000)]
      0x00007f64b4027800 JavaThread "Worker-5" [_thread_blocked, id=3132, stack(0x00007f64741e9000,0x00007f64742ea000)]
      0x00007f64a400a800 JavaThread "Worker-4" [_thread_blocked, id=3131, stack(0x00007f64742ea000,0x00007f64743eb000)]
      0x00007f6470034000 JavaThread "[ThreadPool Manager] - Idle Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3130, stack(0x00007f64744eb000,0x00007f64745ec000)]
      0x00007f64bd3e5000 JavaThread "JavaScript indexing" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3126, stack(0x00007f6474b7c000,0x00007f6474c7d000)]
      0x00007f64a4001800 JavaThread "Worker-3" [_thread_blocked, id=3125, stack(0x00007f6474a7b000,0x00007f6474b7c000)]
      0x00007f64bd715000 JavaThread "EventAdmin Async Event Dispatcher Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3122, stack(0x00007f64842e7000,0x00007f64843e8000)]
      0x00007f6498001000 JavaThread "Worker-2" [_thread_blocked, id=3120, stack(0x00007f647472c000,0x00007f647482d000)]
      0x0000000001403000 JavaThread "Worker-1" [_thread_blocked, id=3119, stack(0x00007f6477831000,0x00007f6477932000)]
      0x00007f64bd308000 JavaThread "Java indexing" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3118, stack(0x00007f6477932000,0x00007f6477a33000)]
      0x00007f6478112800 JavaThread "Bundle File Closer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3117, stack(0x00007f6477bab000,0x00007f6477cac000)]
      0x00007f64bcbac800 JavaThread "Worker-0" [_thread_blocked, id=3115, stack(0x00007f64845ea000,0x00007f64846eb000)]
      0x00007f64bc6cb800 JavaThread "EMF Reference Cleaner" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3110, stack(0x00007f64841e6000,0x00007f64842e7000)]
      0x0000000001395800 JavaThread "Worker-JM" [_thread_blocked, id=3107, stack(0x00007f64843e8000,0x00007f64844e9000)]
      0x00007f6470053000 JavaThread "[Timer] - Main Queue Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3106, stack(0x00007f64844e9000,0x00007f64845ea000)]
      0x00007f64bc5aa800 JavaThread "Start Level: Equinox Container: 807da408-7504-0014-1add-b3822bedfc68" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3104, stack(0x00007f64846eb000,0x00007f64847ec000)]
      0x00007f64bc5c6800 JavaThread "Framework Event Dispatcher: Equinox Container: 807da408-7504-0014-1add-b3822bedfc68" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3103, stack(0x00007f648c055000,0x00007f648c156000)]
      0x00007f64bc541000 JavaThread "Active Thread: Equinox Container: 807da408-7504-0014-1add-b3822bedfc68" [_thread_blocked, id=3102, stack(0x00007f64b00e4000,0x00007f64b01e5000)]
      0x00007f64bc129000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3098, stack(0x00007f64b8316000,0x00007f64b8417000)]
      0x00007f64bc127000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3097, stack(0x00007f64b8417000,0x00007f64b8518000)]
      0x00007f64bc124000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3096, stack(0x00007f64b8518000,0x00007f64b8619000)]
      0x00007f64bc121800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3095, stack(0x00007f64b8619000,0x00007f64b871a000)]
      0x00007f64bc0ff000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3094, stack(0x00007f64b8dfe000,0x00007f64b8eff000)]
      0x00007f64bc0fd000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3093, stack(0x00007f64b8eff000,0x00007f64b9000000)]
    =>0x00007f64bc00a800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=3089, stack(0x00007f64c472a000,0x00007f64c482b000)]

    Other Threads:
      0x00007f64bc0f8800 VMThread [stack: 0x00007f64c00ae000,0x00007f64c01af000] [id=3092]
      0x00007f64bc133800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x00007f64b8215000,0x00007f64b8316000] [id=3099]

    VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

    VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

    Heap
     PSYoungGen      total 125440K, used 118665K [0x00000000f5500000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
      eden space 87040K, 93% used [0x00000000f5500000,0x00000000fa4aac58,0x00000000faa00000)
      from space 38400K, 96% used [0x00000000fd700000,0x00000000ffb378b8,0x00000000ffc80000)
      to   space 44032K, 0% used [0x00000000faa00000,0x00000000faa00000,0x00000000fd500000)
     ParOldGen       total 83968K, used 59960K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e5200000, 0x00000000f5500000)
      object space 83968K, 71% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e3a8e310,0x00000000e5200000)
     PSPermGen       total 88064K, used 87834K [0x00000000d0000000, 0x00000000d5600000, 0x00000000e0000000)
      object space 88064K, 99% used [0x00000000d0000000,0x00000000d55c6a60,0x00000000d5600000)

    Card table byte_map: [0x00007f64c122d000,0x00007f64c13ae000] byte_map_base: 0x00007f64c0bad000

    Polling page: 0x00007f64c4848000

    Code Cache  [0x00007f64b9000000, 0x00007f64b9410000, 0x00007f64bc000000)
     total_blobs=1765 nmethods=1075 adapters=642 free_code_cache=45105Kb largest_free_block=46124288

    Compilation events (10 events):
    Event: 54,499 Thread 0x00007f64bc124000 nmethod 1238 0x00007f64b93bb8d0 code [0x00007f64b93bba00, 0x00007f64b93bba78]
    Event: 54,523 Thread 0x00007f64bc127000 nmethod 1237% 0x00007f64b93e0b10 code [0x00007f64b93e0d00, 0x00007f64b93e1758]
    Event: 56,222 Thread 0x00007f64bc124000 1241             org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable::hook (141 bytes)
    Event: 56,236 Thread 0x00007f64bc124000 nmethod 1241 0x00007f64b93bfbd0 code [0x00007f64b93bfd60, 0x00007f64b93c0498]
    Event: 56,345 Thread 0x00007f64bc127000 1242             org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext::getCalculatedComputations (31 bytes)
    Event: 56,359 Thread 0x00007f64bc127000 nmethod 1242 0x00007f64b93852d0 code [0x00007f64b9385460, 0x00007f64b9385768]
    Event: 56,397 Thread 0x00007f64bc124000 1243             org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager::update (278 bytes)
    Event: 56,440 Thread 0x00007f64bc124000 nmethod 1243 0x00007f64b9386290 code [0x00007f64b93864c0, 0x00007f64b9386d70]
    Event: 56,818 Thread 0x00007f64bc127000 1244             org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.CompositeExpression::evaluateAnd (70 bytes)
    Event: 56,829 Thread 0x00007f64bc127000 nmethod 1244 0x00007f64b93bf250 code [0x00007f64b93bf3e0, 0x00007f64b93bf718]

    GC Heap History (10 events):
    Event: 20,073 GC heap before
    {Heap before GC invocations=8 (full 1):
     PSYoungGen      total 75776K, used 73602K [0x00000000f5500000, 0x00000000fb280000, 0x0000000100000000)
      eden space 59904K, 100% used [0x00000000f5500000,0x00000000f8f80000,0x00000000f8f80000)
      from space 15872K, 86% used [0x00000000fa100000,0x00000000fae60b68,0x00000000fb080000)
      to   space 17920K, 0% used [0x00000000f8f80000,0x00000000f8f80000,0x00000000fa100000)
     ParOldGen       total 45056K, used 30981K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e2c00000, 0x00000000f5500000)
      object space 45056K, 68% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e1e41570,0x00000000e2c00000)
     PSPermGen       total 38400K, used 38139K [0x00000000d0000000, 0x00000000d2580000, 0x00000000e0000000)
      object space 38400K, 99% used [0x00000000d0000000,0x00000000d253ec78,0x00000000d2580000)
    Event: 20,164 GC heap after
    Heap after GC invocations=8 (full 1):
     PSYoungGen      total 77824K, used 17908K [0x00000000f5500000, 0x00000000fd480000, 0x0000000100000000)
      eden space 59904K, 0% used [0x00000000f5500000,0x00000000f5500000,0x00000000f8f80000)
      from space 17920K, 99% used [0x00000000f8f80000,0x00000000fa0fd200,0x00000000fa100000)
      to   space 24576K, 0% used [0x00000000fbc80000,0x00000000fbc80000,0x00000000fd480000)
     ParOldGen       total 45056K, used 38448K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e2c00000, 0x00000000f5500000)
      object space 45056K, 85% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e258c130,0x00000000e2c00000)
     PSPermGen       total 38400K, used 38139K [0x00000000d0000000, 0x00000000d2580000, 0x00000000e0000000)
      object space 38400K, 99% used [0x00000000d0000000,0x00000000d253ec78,0x00000000d2580000)
    }
    Event: 20,164 GC heap before
    {Heap before GC invocations=9 (full 2):
     PSYoungGen      total 77824K, used 17908K [0x00000000f5500000, 0x00000000fd480000, 0x0000000100000000)
      eden space 59904K, 0% used [0x00000000f5500000,0x00000000f5500000,0x00000000f8f80000)
      from space 17920K, 99% used [0x00000000f8f80000,0x00000000fa0fd200,0x00000000fa100000)
      to   space 24576K, 0% used [0x00000000fbc80000,0x00000000fbc80000,0x00000000fd480000)
     ParOldGen       total 45056K, used 38448K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000e2c00000, 0x00000000f5500000)
      object space 45056K, 85% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e258c130,0x00000000e2c00000)
     PSPermGen       total 38400K, used 38139K [0x00000000d0000000, 0x00000000d2580000, 0x00000000e0000000)
      object space 38400K, 99% used [0x00000000d0000000,0x00000000d253ec78,0x00000000d2580000)
    Event: 20,705 GC heap after
    Heap after GC invocations=9 (full 2):
VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xms40m -Xmx512m 
java_command: /home/gabriel/Área de Trabalho/Eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -showsplash /home/gabriel/Área de Trabalho/Eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.4.0.v20140606-1215/splash.bmp -launcher /home/gabriel/Área de Trabalho/Eclipse/eclipse -name Eclipse --launcher.library /home/gabriel/Área de Trabalho/Eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326/eclipse_1605.so -startup /home/gabriel/Área de Trabalho/Eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar --launcher.appendVmargs -exitdata 918000 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -vm /usr/bin/java -vmargs -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xms40m -Xmx512m -jar /home/gabriel/Área de Trabalho/Eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
SHELL=/bin/bash
DISPLAY=:0.0
```

Well, i really need to do WEB aplications, anyone knows how to fix it ? Btw, i'm using Linux, Ubuntu 13.10. Thx!

Comment: Did you use the Java EE edition of eclipse? Which server did you try to add? Did you try Oracle JDK instead of Open JDK?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? If so, please share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get this error if your using Open JDK instead Oracle JDK. Best option is to switch to the Oracle JDK and check the issue.

There is an article explaining [how to change the default JDK](http://kosalads.blogspot.com/2013/02/install-jdk7-on-ubuntu-1210.html)